# How to alter REQUEST_URI using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this folder structure:

> /www/project/web/app.php

I can access it via `/project/web/index.php`. The problem is that I do not want to have `web/` as part of the URL. It should be `/project/index.php`.

With this .htaccess in `/www/project/` folder:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [L]

It seems to reroute to the correct file when accessed via `/project/foo/bar`, however, the REQUEST_URI stays intact and is `/project/index.php/foo/bar` which breaks many things.

How can I change the REQUEST_URI to not contain the `project`?

To put it simply:

**/www/project/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [L]
```

Accessing the URL `/project/foo/bar` correctly reroutes to `index.php`, but the application fails because REQUEST_URI contains `/project/foo/bar` instead of `/foo/bar`. `project` is a folder and should not be part of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `/www/project/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/

#first, if project/web or web or just project is present, redirect and remove them
RewriteRule ^(project/web/|web/|project/)(.*)$ $2 [L,R=301]


#next, rewrite all requests to web/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This does not _modify_ the `REQUEST_URI` -- it redirects the client, which then (usually) sends a new request, with the _new_ `REQUEST_URI`...

Answer (score 2):

To change the URI you must use `R` flag for redirection, your current rule will only internally redirect thus keeping the same URI.